# deploy a list with specific item-level permissions in ListAdded event receiver method

Tags: 2010, permissions, event-handlers, event-receivers, list-definition

I have a certain type of custom list I have designed in my 'solution.wsp', that, whenever an instance of it is instantiated, it should have at the outset a specific Item-Level permission.

To further clarify, my custom list is automatically instantiated in a relationship to another list, so, users don't even realize when they instantiated one list, this supporting list is created simultaneously alongside it.

Anyways, I already have a nice ListAdded event that sets up all of the above just how I like it. Unfortunately, at the moment, the Item-Level Permissions for this supporting list have to still be tweaked via the UI.

I saw a lot of stuff on Google (mostly older references to MOSS) about breaking inheritance, etc, which attacked things at the ItemAdded level.. but, I want to set the Item-Level permissions so that users can "Create items and edit items that were created by the user" at the time of list creation (before any items are ever added/edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a ListAdded event receiver for that.

In your [ListTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462947.aspx) just set the attribute `SecurityBits` to "22"

Answer (score 1):

In your listadded event, after you create your list, set the following properties.

```
list.ReadSecurity = 2
list.WriteSecurity = 2
```

This sets the properties to allow users to create, edit, view their own content. Setting 1 to the property gives users read, write access on all the items. 
Ref: [SPList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist_properties)