# EventReciever to change permissions

Tags: development, document-library, permissions, event-receivers

I am trying to create an event reciever on a document library that on creation it removes all permissions and gives the author contribute writes. All other users get nothing.

I have the following

element.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="101">
      <Receiver>
        <Name>Asset_Store_EventsItemAdded</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>Asset_Store.SP.EventReceivers.Asset_Store_Events.Asset_Store_Events</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>

  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

And then my code

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);


    var item = properties.ListItem;

    item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
    // Remove All Permissions
    while (item.RoleAssignments.Count > 0)
    {
        item.RoleAssignments.Remove(0);
    }

    var web = properties.Web;

    var authorID = int.Parse(item.Properties["Author"].ToString());
    var user = web.Users[authorID];


    SPRoleDefinition spRole = web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];

    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(user.LoginName, user.Email, user.Name, user.Notes);
    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(spRole);

    item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);

    item.Update();

}
```

However when I add a document to the library nothing is happening... What could be going wrong?

**Update**

It does help if you include the event handler in your feature...

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);

    var item = properties.ListItem;

    item.BreakRoleInheritance(false);


    var web = properties.Web;

    var authorLoginName = (string)item.Properties["vti_author"];
    var user = web.Users[authorLoginName];


    SPRoleDefinition spRole = web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];

    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(user.LoginName, user.Email, user.Name, user.Notes);
    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(spRole);

    item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using the SPList.ReadSecurity and SPList.WriteSecurity (see this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39033/deploy-a-list-with-specific-item-level-permissions-in-listadded-event-receiver-m/39055#39055)). This allows you to set contribute permissions to the particular item only for the current user and remove all role assignments for others. Also event receivers might not work if you are doing bulk upload.

If that does't work for you, in your event receiver, you can stat by checking if the event receiver is actually registered. You can check the properties SPList.EventReceivers, SPWeb.EventReceivers, SPSite.EventReceivers depending on the event receiver scope.

Also you might want to replace

```
item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
    // Remove All Permissions
    while (item.RoleAssignments.Count > 0)
    {
        item.RoleAssignments.Remove(0);
    }
```

with `item.BreakRoleInheritance(false);`.

Also verify if you are actually getting SPUser object in user variable.

Comment: Do you have any more info regarding bulk upload

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx . I have written a similar code some time back, and back then event receiver failed to run when the administrator did a bulk upload (i.e. open in folder explorer and drag and drop files). So you might have to handle this scenario. I also found this nice article which might help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979520.aspx.